# Angular UI-grid, how to tell what the next column in the scroll is

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a ui grid that has 20 columns, and I would like to be able to tell what the next column will be as I scroll through the horizontal axis so that I can have some text that will tell the users what the names of all the columns they can't see are.

Anyone know if this is possible? As I watch the the inspector and scroll through the columns, I see html attributes changing.

---UPDATE 1----
This is what is all looks like (where it says "home #" is dynamic and will change to show the next column that is out of site)
[image]

Comment: Where do you want to show this to the user?

Comment: outside of the grid, I have some text with an arrow "Home Phone ->" which shows the user the next column (that is beyond the view), so when the scroll horizontally, that is the next column they will see

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ui-grid configuration that you use to render the grid, you already know the order of the columns. You can use this information together with the `visible` on each column added by the gird itself.

What you need to do is bind a event handler on scroll to iterate over the columns on each change and check the visibility of them. Then the first one with `visible === false` is the upcoming.

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOhuwEpBnNSCQQLQ19BR?p=preview) where is used this flag.

Comment: @IWI fixed the link, sorry.